# Shouldn't strict-aliasing kick in in this code?

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

Take this toy code:

```cpp
void f(const int& a, int* dat) {
    
    for (int i=0; i<a; ++i )
      dat[i] += a;
}
```

[Observe](https://godbolt.org/z/PGTfczxqK) that the compiler is afraid that `dat[i]` might alias with `a`, i.e. writing to `dat[i]` might change the value of `a` - and so it feels obliged to re-load `a` on every loop iteration  (that's the 'movslq  (%rdi), %rax' line at the link).

This could be solved with strict-aliasing, by changing the type of dat:

```cpp
void f(const int& a, long* dat) {
...
```

The [generated code seems Indeed longer](https://godbolt.org/z/aE1bM3G7n), but that's due to vectorization. It doesn't re-load `a` on every iteration.

I'm surprised this doesn't work for my own *custom* type!

```cpp
struct myInt {
    int i;
    myInt& operator+=(int rhs) { i += rhs; return *this;}
};

void f(const int& a, myInt* dat) {
    
    for (int i=0; i<a; ++i )
      dat[i] += a;
}
```

Here [the compiler returns to re-loading the loop boundary on every iteration](https://godbolt.org/z/seaT31hs7).  Both clang and gcc do.

Looks like the compiler's alias-analysis treats `myInt` as a regular `int` - which is reasonable in many aspects, but causes this optimization to be missed. Could this be a compiler bug? Or is there something I'm missing about strict-aliasing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it a strict aliasing violation to alias a struct as its first member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50383187/is-it-a-strict-aliasing-violation-to-alias-a-struct-as-its-first-member)

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I don't see how.  There isn't any statement here about aliasing struct-members to the struct.

Comment: `restrict` could help getting strict aliasing.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica   I think I understand your point now, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine the following:

```
struct myInt {
    int i;
    myInt& operator+=(int rhs) { i += rhs; return *this;}
};

void f(const int& a, myInt* dat) 
{
    for (int i=0; i<a; ++i)
      dat[i] += a;
}

int main()
{
   myInt foo{ 1 };
   f(foo.i, &foo);
}
```

In this program, `a` and `dat.i` actually alias. They are the same variable. So the compiler actually needs to reload one after a write to the other.

Comment: That could have been said for the second (optimized) code as well: `int a = 1;  f(a, (long*)&a)`.   And yet the compiler optimizes it. Strict-aliasing is exactly the permission we give the compiler to assume that if two objects have different types they do not alias.

Comment: In the code you present, your typecast is a reinterpret cast. If you reinterpret cast values to types they are not, you are _asking_ for aliasing issues (among others)

Comment: Indeed - and the compiler is not required to protect me from myself in such cases. If the static types of `a` and `dat` differ - the compiler is allowed to deduce they don't alias..

Comment: @OfekShilon The snippet here is legal, while `f(a, (long*)&a)` is not.

Comment: I think I see your point, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure no aliasing happens, most compilers support restrict from C99:

```cpp
void f(const int& __restrict a, int* dat) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i) dat[i] += a;
}
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/76rWqj41x)

Note that this is dangerous code. A better option would be to take `a` by value:

```
void f(const int a, int* dat) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i) dat[i] += a;
}
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/h6GeqMe4x)

Comment: Note that both clang and gcc are prone to behave weirdly if pointer-equality operators happen to observe that the address which is based upon a restrict-qualified pointer equals an address which is not based upon that pointer.  The way the C Standard is written makes it possible to argue that, given `if (restrictedPointer == otherPointer) *restrictedPointer = 3;`, the pointer which is used conditionally to store the number 3 isn't based upon the value of `restrictedPointer` outside the `if` statement, and both gcc and clang will sometimes treat it as not based upon that value.